# Regex matching a character where its not surrounded by a space

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

Ok, this is a bit tricky with my limited regex experience and although I've spent the last 30 mins googling, I suspect its a bit too specific to be easy to find.

Basically what I need to do is search a string for a `-` character and if there are *no spaces around it*, replace it with '`-`'.

For example:

"Airoh Goggles-black" wants to become "Airoh Goggles - black"

same with:

"Airoh Goggles- black" and "Airoh Goggles -black"

I did look into *lookaheads* and *behinds*, but couldn't get it to work.

Any help appreciated - if it matters, its going to be used in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('/\s*-\s*/', ' - ', $target);
```

Comment: That does match both 'Airoh Goggles - black' and 'Airoh Goggles-black' but as its standardising to ' - ' it doesn't really matter.

Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question. I interpreted it as "make sure each hyphen is surrounded by exactly one space character on both sides, irrespective of whether either or both sides had spaces to begin with". If that's an incorrect interpretation, then another answer is probably what you want. If you're going to use this answer, then please accept it :)